# Python - Executable Directory Import Issues

Tags: python, directory, executable

I am working through an online python course and have an issue that I am having trouble working through. I have a executable directory with the following layout

```
reader/
|--__main__.py
|--reader
   |--__init__.py
   |--reader.py
   |--compressed
      |--gzipped.py
      |--bzipped.py
      |--__init__.py
```

When I do not have these modules in the top directory, I can import just fine and use all of the functionality. When I put them in the top level directory and run the executable directory from the command line with

```
python reader test.gz
```

I am getting the following error

```
AttributeError: module 'reader' has not attribute 'Reader'
```

The code for **main**.py is

```
import sys
import reader

r = reader.Reader(sys.argv[1])

try:
    print(r.read())
finally:
    r.close()
```

The code for reader.py is

```
import os

from reader.compressed import gzipped, bzipped

extension_map = {
    '.bz2': bzipped.opener,
    '.gz': gzipped.opener,
}

class Reader:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
        opener = extension_map.get(extension, open)
        self.f = opener(filename, 'rt')

    def close(self):
        self.f.close()

    def read(self):
        return self.f.read()
```

I can provide the rest of the files if needed. I am using the current distribution of Anaconda. Any help or explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: Also this is running on Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that because of your `__init__.py` file the folder `reader` is seen as a python module. Thereore your `main.py` code tries to find the class `Reader` at the folder level, but you need to look for `Reader` within `reader.py`. Can you try changing

`r = reader.Reader(sys.argv[1])`

to

`r = reader.reader.Reader(sys.argv[1])`

Also, you have a lot of modules/files/modules called reader, e.g. the class `Reader` is in `reader/reader/reader.py`. This I would try to avoid as it can lead to confusion.

Comment: That caused the same error. I made the top directory exeDir and I know that the __init__.py file is running when

`import reader`

is called. Is there supposed to be some sort of import in the __init__.py file?

In PyCharm the duck typing trace it does say that the model could not be found.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the `__init__.py` file but it shoulnd be necessary to import things there. However you can try importing the `Reader` class there (`from reader import Reader`)

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple modules/modules that are named identically you can often get the namespace into a recursive loop.  Also, the Reader class is capitalized.

Like mentioned above, try **python reader.reader test.gz**

While you are troubleshooting try the tab-complete feature to see if your modules are being loaded properly.

Comment: See above. It resulted in telling me that reader.reader.compressed does not exist.